# check if Facebook auth code expired rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala, koala-gem

I'm trying to comply with the new Dec. 5th Facebook release, and store access tokens. I'm using the Koala gem in Rails for the Facebook API.

I ge the following error if the user has logged out of Facebook, but not our app

```
Koala::Facebook::APIError (OAuthException: This authorization code has expired.):
```

I used to just call this:

```
@oauth.get_user_info_from_cookies(cookies)
```

But now that Facebook only allows you to call this once...is there another way to see if the cookie expired?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook OAuthException: This authorization code has been used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769989/facebook-oauthexception-this-authorization-code-has-been-used)