# Do Facebook Oauth 2.0 authorization code Expire?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

The Facebook OAuth Access Tokens Expire after a specified period, but what about Facebook OAuth authorization code?  does it expire? (it does not say?)

Reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#page-8

Answer (score 1):

The authorization code has an expiration.

From the docs : Now that your app has authorization from the user and the code parameter stored as a variable, it should immediately exchange it for a User access token that can then be used to make API requests

The following post also mentions a facebook update informing about authorization code expiration :

[OAuthException: This authorization code has been used - Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752959/oauthexception-this-authorization-code-has-been-used-facebook)